# Is there an alternative to themegarden.org - one that has Drupal 7 themes?

Tags: 7, theming

I like themegarden.org and I think it'll be a useful tool to help me explain to clients and colleagues how content and presentation can and should be separated. It looks like Theme Garden only caters for Drupal 4.7, 5 and 6. Does anyone know of a D7-compatible site where I can browse themes as easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't come across a really good site for Drupal 7 themes. Here are some sites that might be helpful:

- http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/colin/10-free-drupal-themes-7x
- http://omega.developmentgeeks.com/
- http://www.themesnap.com/drupal-themes.html (paid)
- http://adaptivethemes.com/drupal-themes/all (paid)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following sites which claim to Theme Garden:

- http://drupal7themes.arxic.com/
- http://drupal7themegallery.com/theme-gallery (searchable!)

Both are free.